# transistor as an amplifier in detail from ncert book of class xiith

Tags: transistors

While going through transistor as an amplifier in detail from ncert book of class 12th(*),

m finding after equation 14.16,when it says when input voltage vi is not zero,we get,$$ V_{BE}+v_i = V_{BE} + I_BR_B + \Delta I_B (R_B + r_i)$$

m finding there is a printing error in this, it should be VBB not VBE in VBE+vi as it is a continuation of equation 14.16,it should be

$$V_{BB} +v_i = V_{BE} + I_BR_B + \Delta I_B (R_B + r_i),$$

where from eqation 14.16 VBB equals VBE+IBRB and vi equals delta IB (RB+ri),

---

*: See page-498 of this [freely available pdf](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph206.pdf)

Comment: This is not the platform to discuss typographical errors in textbooks. Your image is not of sufficient resolution to easily read and there may be some copyright issues with posting images of the text whether you water mark it or not.

Comment: @sachinrath123 Hello again! I have edited your post to latexify the equations and I linked a pdf of ncert to avoid copy right issues ^^

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg on the page of that pdf, that line is written for deriving working of transistor as amplifier but OP thinks it's wrong he wishes to know if his thinking is right

Comment: @Phil Freedenberg,i think the equation should be VBB+vi=VBE+IBRB+ΔIB(RB+ri),not VBE+vi=VBE+IBRB+ΔIB(RB+ri),thanks.

Comment: @ Buraian,thanks.